# Should Rollback be issued before raise application error?

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

This is a portion of my procedure. The Rollback did not happen when the procedure failed. 
   1. Should the Rollback be issued before raise application error? 
   2. In that case will backtrace work with raise application error. It is tracked in log table . However want to know if raise application error will issue correctly backtrace if rollbacked.

```
EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
    /*Log that some other error occured and backtrace*/
    eps_datareduction_run_log ( 5, 'CREDIT', current_timestamp,  'FAILED', 'CREDIT: Error Number:'||sqlcode||'Error Code:'||substr(sqlerrm, 1, 200)||'-backtrace:'||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace, sysdate, user, null, null );
    lv_err_msg := 'Unexcpected Error '||SUBSTR(sqlerrm,1,255);
    raise_application_error(-20000,lv_err_msg || '- backtrace - ' || dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
    ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: Place the rollback exactly after `EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN` and do other logics after it.

Comment: Your script is terminated when it issued `raise_application_error` and `ROLLBACK` never executes.

Comment: It might be a good idea to amend  `eps_datareduction_run_log` so that it captures the error and call stack details itself and every single call to it doesn’t have to build an elaborate concatenated string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Rollback` should be issued first, then do all logical operation you want to do in Log tables and then `Raise`. `Raise` is kind of the end part of program, which technically tells user that this specific error has occurred and program have ended.

Answer (score 0):

See if there's a COMMIT inside eps_datareduction_run_log? That could be the reason why rollback didn't occur. It's still a good idea to rollback before any other actions in exception handler and use autonomous_transaction pragma in your logging subroutines.